# Using a class with a constructor as a type parameter in a template instantiation in c++

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

In C++ (14) I have a template class with a type T for which I would like to use a class as the type. The class that I want to use for the type requires a parameter in its constructor... so how do I pass this parameter through the template instantiation?

My example code (template_hell.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class my_template
{
public:
  struct Stored_Data_Type
  {
    T data;
    int set_count = 0;
  };

  my_template() : m_data() {};

  T& write()
  {
    m_data.set_count++;
    return m_data.data;
  }

  const T& get() const {return m_data.data;}

private:
  Stored_Data_Type m_data;
};

class a_class
{
public:

  a_class(int init): m_data(init) {};

  void set(const int data) {m_data = data;};

  const int get() const {return m_data;};

private:
  int m_data;
};

class b_class : public a_class
{
public:
  b_class(): a_class{0} {};
};

int main()
{
  //a_class b(1);
  b_class b;
  b.set(2);
  std::cout << "b: " << b.get() << std::endl;

  my_template<int> my_int;
  my_int.write() = 10;
  std::cout << "my_int: " << my_int.get() << std::endl;

  my_template<b_class> my_b;
  my_b.write().set(2);
  std::cout << "my_b: " << my_b.get().get() << std::endl;

  // Compile error here:
  my_template<a_class> my_a;
  my_a.write().set(3);
  std::cout << "my_a: " << my_a.get().get() << std::endl;
}
```

This all works and is fine until I add in the `my_a` template instance. Then I get this compile error:

```
template_hell.cpp: In instantiation of 'my_template<T>::my_template() [with T = a_class]':
template_hell.cpp:62:24:   required from here
template_hell.cpp:13:26: error: use of deleted function 'my_template<a_class>::Stored_Data_Type::Stored_Data_Type()'
   my_template() : m_data() {};
                          ^
template_hell.cpp:7:10: note: 'my_template<a_class>::Stored_Data_Type::Stored_Data_Type()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   struct Stored_Data_Type
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
template_hell.cpp:7:10: error: no matching function for call to 'a_class::a_class()'
template_hell.cpp:31:3: note: candidate: a_class::a_class(int)
   a_class(int init): m_data(init) {};
   ^~~~~~~
template_hell.cpp:31:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
template_hell.cpp:27:7: note: candidate: constexpr a_class::a_class(const a_class&)
 class a_class
       ^~~~~~~
template_hell.cpp:27:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
template_hell.cpp:27:7: note: candidate: constexpr a_class::a_class(a_class&&)
template_hell.cpp:27:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

How do I pass the parameter to a_class through the template instance? Is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of Variadic arguments. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack. This allows us to forward on any arguments to the `StoredDataType` that are passed to our `my_template` class

Variadic templates allow us to write classes/methods that take an arbitrary number of arguments in a type-safe way and have all the argument handling logic resolved at compile-time, rather than run-time

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class my_template
{
public:
  struct Stored_Data_Type
  {
      template<typename... TArgs>
      Stored_Data_Type(TArgs&&... args) : data(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...)
      {

      }

    T data;
    int set_count = 0;
  };

  template<typename... TArgs>
  my_template(TArgs&&... args) : m_data(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...) {}

  T& write()
  {
    m_data.set_count++;
    return m_data.data;
  }

  const T& get() const {return m_data.data;}

private:
  Stored_Data_Type m_data;
};

class a_class
{
public:

  a_class(int init): m_data(init) {};

  void set(const int data) {m_data = data;};

  const int get() const {return m_data;};

private:
  int m_data;
};

class b_class : public a_class
{
public:
  b_class(): a_class{0} {};
};

int main()
{
  //a_class b(1);
  b_class b;
  b.set(2);
  std::cout << "b: " << b.get() << std::endl;

  my_template<int> my_int;
  my_int.write() = 10;
  std::cout << "my_int: " << my_int.get() << std::endl;

  my_template<b_class> my_b;
  my_b.write().set(2);
  std::cout << "my_b: " << my_b.get().get() << std::endl;

  // Compile error here:
  my_template<a_class> my_a(1);
  std::cout << "my_a: " << my_a.get().get() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The parameters should be declared `TArgs&&... args` to enable perfect forwarding and prevent unnecessary copies. Using `std::forward` doesn't help much without that.

Comment: Good spot, this is what happens when you code on stack overflow ;)

Answer (score 4):

You are passing `a_class` as a template parameter to the `my_template` template class and, since inside `my_template` class `Stored_Data_Type m_data;` is an object of following `struct`

```cpp
struct Stored_Data_Type {
    a_class data;
    int set_count = 0;
};
```

`m_data` member is default constructed with

```cpp
my_template() : m_data() {}
```

which tries to call `a_class`'s default constructor which you haven't defined.

Therefore, you just need to define default constructor for your `a_class` class:

```cpp
class a_class {
public:
    a_class()
        : m_data{0}
    {}

    // ...
};
```

Check [live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLgGZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEuAVlIAHVAsLqtHqGJuY%2BfgF0tvZORq7unF5KKmp0DATMxATBxqacFsmYqoHpmQTRji5unooZWTmh%2BbVlFbHxngCUiqgGxMgcAORSZnbIhlgA1OJmOuoKBMSYzEbT2OIADACCG5sEmEbewntTMwQAnt5ay5gTACqrO2PMCgoTRmcA%2BnsHR5g74gB2WRbbwGZysPDIEA7CYTebEAyqCbpEiYdAfAAizAyH1uFz%2BW1hgOBm1hsNuE3Q2OY0xJZImdgIcMwBA%2BaAM9BOGIm61pMKmAIxfK2/PeX32h2xmAgHQmIDeHypGRlAtkguF20JdykADYJgB3YiEaUdfnE/mwoyK6kAOiUrPZ9DkzrMdLJiwIvVoCqVzBtvo1RPVIq1aFo821kj1wBZKrDEeJHq9PttAddgKFIc23iNADcpdCtSjFuisTi8ZcUxkNRma1sni8Jsw2cIXv8gTtQeDIYXSU2W88FCr5VaA0DeYLVbWs7Dmw2h4yGbRCB0R9blXYV1P1emZxNc6g8OhmQQIPGmYvfbLiaPqVzKdS%2BTuSfzz0umTHT7K34mWcnb9W6bPv8IJ5gW/KLgBNK7tswFZvOEzOAOjbyl2ELIP287tiSaE9vySHzjK8pzq2CjEhO3LmnBsFCjBOyQcwdgyth/IAPSsSRg6IRAnCmjBsIEaRiGBohdqxpIfFuvM6AgCgPRMtMOiKVMkiSM48pSJIJxKTMomfiqinKdJslWKwdZ9mK3ySnsimMqsbyfHZ/EOR8jI2oaxoGWY3KcLyznGXJBgKTMymaWKjIaap2nKeF9A2vp14hbpAWmeZlqfFZvyKYJg72WKzgifl7lGnsMpiaeEkiQF7LBTpOgqZI%2BWRVphm6UVCXxbGiV1XCBAySAqV0Vq7ETHoBx4OwExuMQJATAgbgcKKGUSllMycW2ZjYC50FumKfoeaVHTlRAZiSfy1XydFulhZ8zDNVd9V7Z1X7PV5PUpdoZl0YKAxdKwIADB4AykKYAzrMDqAA0pMhyHCPR9DcwycMDBAA%2BDHRdAA1iA3AAJw2gAHB4ePcDqZhmOsPCSJwOpCAD3DA6D4OkJDAzAwoIDrKQqNg79pBwLAMCIHJ43sGQFBnqgovVMAuOSKQVATXsxAcxA6m86Qzh2JkZwA8jpBoEYRhaAQADytCsLrGtYEYIjAOwaPA/gizFLmmAcxrmAAB5FEFgzM4yyiO0IeDOMQOt6Fgeso0aRjR10ND0EwbAcDw/AgPLwiiCgzoyCHzgc5AXSoN4qThgDAC00nTBiEgwzIPDs8oRRl5o2gNHkljaK0VQJOE/hlx3gi%2BAPgQ93E1ScIozfFGkdTZPouSCIUs%2B0KUWTj%2B0U/zGUQ/b/Pm%2BT10Cjw/0XB/QDQMg8HrNewTOoVzq3ATMAyAYfjWkQLghCzUjpCjVLbwE03AqTMBJUaudpAo0dhjUg2MPDrBtDwBBHgzA6h1LjImAICbcC8P9AYDNSBxwQdfDWrN2ac25jA/mQsIBIHkqCAg5BKCGyAWLDOlh8BED7onRgLAHZp0NMwbw8c6aA0ZjfAGwwtL6kIAgCYd8H5Pxfm/CYH9oG81gfNZgWB3AyjEYQ4hXMmYQwBhQrmPN0ZYxAAgpBuD1ioPQZgjw2DcFiLMBIshZiqGaIvgMSQnjmbkJ8VY0gbsVaBBxkAA%3D%3D%3D)

Comment: or could change my_template to allow forwarding of variadic params

Comment: @const_ref yes. I will update my answer with this in the morning

Comment: I have posted an answer. Both methods are worth pointing out.

Comment: @const_ref agree. +1 from me

Comment: While this is helpful and correct (and what b_class is doing), I can only accept 1 answer... so @const_ref answer is more inline with what I'm trying to accomplish... so he wins this round :)

Comment: @Brian sure. Just accept the answer which helped you and which you will use eventually in your case